# what will happen to if value of x defined as "int x;" and value of y defined as "int y = 1;" and use min(x,y) in C++?

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
    int x;
    int y = 1;
    int minNumber = min(x,y);
    cout << minNumber;
    return 0;
}
```

I know x and y are different initialization. But I do not know what excatly happen when I call min() function. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour due to using the value of an uninitialized variable

Answer (score 2):

It is undefined behavior because `x` is uninitialized non static local variable.

Comment: The bit about "is undefined" is correct. "contains random value" is misleading.

Comment: "contains any value" is still misleading. Undefined behavior means that the language definition does not tell you what the code does. Yes, typically you get a value that is informally described as "random", but that's not required. Formally, the program can do anything.

Answer (score 1):

x is not initialized and hence it would have some value as per what's there in memory location which is assigned for x, by the system. min function's return value will be unpredictable, in this case.

Comment: I misread the question. Later updated my answer.

Comment: Not only does `x` have an unpredictable value, using it also causes undefined behavior.